# Access struct member from pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've some problems of segmentation fault with this code:

```
void init(int max, pile * p) {
    p = (pile *)malloc(sizeof(pile));
    if(p){
        p->nbElemPresent = 0;
        p->maxElem       = max;
        p->tete          = (data *)malloc(max * sizeof(data));
    }
}

short int vide(pile * p) {
    if(p->maxElem == 0) {return 1;}
    return 0;
}
```

my function vide  return me segfault.. I don't know how to access to struct member from the p pointer.

The main program:

```
pile * p;
init(5, p);
printf("%d", vide(p));
```

ty.

Comment: If the seg fault is happening in `vide()`, then most likely the argument being passed in is NULL. Check for this before accessing the field.

Comment: In function `init`, add a `*` next to every occurrence of `p`. Wherever you call function `init`, add an `&` next to the second argument that you pass to this function.

Comment: The function `init` has no effect. It isn't doing what you imagine it should be doing.

Comment: Yes i think it's my init function who dont make his job. I dont make task if p is null, i'll change and see if it's here the problem

Comment: A good prototype for function `init()` would be `void init(int max, pile ** p)` . This is required to keep an access to the allocated memory, avoid memory leaks and segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by barak manos, your problem lies in `init`. C pass parameters by value so let's imagine :

- you set a pointer to pile to NULL (`pile *p = NULL;`)
- you pass it to init (`init(p);`)
- in init you alloc a pile and affect is **to the local copy of p**
- on return from init, p is still NULL and you have a memory leak since you have no longer any pointer to the allocated pile

That's the reason why you should write :

```
void init(int max, pile ** p) {
    pile *lp = *p = (pile *)malloc(sizeof(pile));
    if(*p){
        lp->nbElemPresent = 0;
        lp->maxElem       = max;
        lp->tete          = (data *)malloc(max * sizeof(data));
    }
}
```

Now you use :

```
pile *p;
init(&p);
```

and on return p points to the allocated pile.

Answer (score 1):

C takes parameters by value, that means that pointer `p` is copied when you pass it to init().
`p` in the function is a completely new variable and if its value is changed that doesn't change the value of `p` passed to the function.

You should pass its address:

```
init(5, &p);

void init(int max, pile** p) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof(pile));
    if(*p){
    (*p)->nbElemPresent = 0;
    ....
    }
}
```

Note the unusual parenthesis `(*p)->nbElemPresent`, this is done because `->` operator has a higher precedence, yet we want to dereference the `p` first.

Comment: this wouldn't work as you did not change the argument type of init

Comment: @PhilippMurry Doh! it was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

as already said, p is a new variable in your init function. other than the other answers suggested, i'd rather suggest not taking p as an argument at all, but instead returning it:

```
pile* init(int max) {
  pile *p = (pile *)malloc(sizeof(pile));
  ...
  return p;

}
```

and in your main function:

```
pile * p = init(5);
printf("%d", vide(p));
```